# number of second deposits

Tags: sql, postgresql

How is it possible to change below mentioned query in order to know all the same data but for second deposits?

```
    select "Manager",
    count(*) as "Number of first deposits",
    sum("Amount, $") as "Sum of first deposits" 
    from
    (SELECT 
    bbt.user_id as "ClientID",
    uu.email as "Email",
    initcap(split_part(man.email,'@',1)) as "Manager",
    bbt.created_at as "Date of transaction",
    bbt.payment as "Amount, $",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY bbt.user_id ORDER BY bbt.created_at) as row_num
    from billing_balancetransaction bbt 
    left join users_user uu on bbt.user_id=uu.id
    left join users_user man on uu.account_manager_id=man.id
    where bbt.executed_at is not null
    and bbt.user_id in ('27241','27255','27298','27276','27342','26572','26227','27282','26612','26068','26069','27853','26288','26523','26911')
    and bbt.payment>0) t
    where row_num=1
    group by 1
```

All users can have different number of deposits (1,2,3,5, etc)

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and remove the filter condition in the `where` clause:

```
select "Manager",
        count(*) filter (where row_num = 1) as num_first_deposits,
        sum("Amount, $") filter (where row_num = 1) as sum_first_deposits,
        count(*) filter (where row_num = 2) as num_second_deposits,
        sum("Amount, $") filter (where row_num = 2) as sum_second_deposits
from (select . . .
     ) t
group by 1
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, sorry, it does not work so.

Comment: @YariyZhlob . . . "Does not work" is pretty useless as a comment.  Are you getting an error?  Are the results off?  Is there a syntax error in the answer?

Comment: Hello, @Gordon Linoff thanks a lot for Your attention. Issue was that ''where as row'' should not contain ''as'' but another part was excellent.